# What happens if I don't complete reputation Requests after starting them?

Tags: genshin-impact

I'm talking about the generic world quests that you can get every week from reputation NPCs.

[image: Reputation Requests screenshot]

I would like to stockpile these quests since they give out Encounter Points, and I might want to use them to skip daily commissions later on.

Can I do that? Will they expire at some point? Is there a limit to how many of them I can hold?

Comment: I guess they'll simply expire with the weeks end. Isn't there a time listed in the quest menu?

Comment: No, there isn't an expiry time listed on them, but that would make sense. Perhaps they just expire anyway.

Comment: I assume that even if they don't expire (and 99.9% they do) you would still be fooled by the small prints: it is not "you can get 3 per week". It is "you can only complete 3 each week".... so sorry, Lady Neko, your plan to farm rep points for 
Asase Shrine won't work (wait, what do you mean by "not *that* cat"? :P )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it for science. The (somewhat expected) answer is that the quest simply disappears with the weekly reset, so you cannot carry them over into different weeks.